# How to retrieve a value from arraylist in Java on click of a hyperlink

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on a Java application eInvoice application. The purpose of app is to add eInvoices and then display the eInvoices I have added (Works totally fine upto here). However when I display invoices I want the company name to be hyperlinked, and after clicking on the link that particular invoice details should be displayed in a Jsp page. Please note I am passing information to servlet and then I am storing the info in java class using getters and Setters. Multiple records are stored in the Arraylist object. I cannot seem to find the way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<%
float bigTotal=0;
try
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<UserInvoice> myVal = (ArrayList<UserInvoice>)session.getAttribute("eInvoice");
    out.write("<table border='0'>");
    out.write("<th width='200'>Invoice No.</th><th width='300'>Client Name</th>  <th width='200'>Total</th><th width='200'>Payment Due Date</th>");
    for(UserInvoice invoices:myVal)
    {
        out.write("<tr>");
        out.write("<td height='25'>");
        out.write(""+invoices.getInvoiceNo());
        out.write("</td>");

        out.write("<td>");
        out.write(invoices.getClientName());
        out.write("</td>");

        out.write("<td>");
        out.write(String.valueOf(invoices.getTotal()));
        out.write("</td>");

        out.write("<td>");
        out.write(invoices.getPayDueDate());
        out.write("</td>");

        out.write("</tr>");
        bigTotal = bigTotal+invoices.getTotal();

    }
    out.write("</table>");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
out.write("<h1>Looks like you haven't added any invoices yet.</h1>");
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.  Probably your jsp

Comment: Hi tie, thanks for your quick response. I have added the code above. This code is used to print all the values from arraylist. Now when the client/company name is printed, it is hyperlinked and going to addInvoice form. I want to display the values of specific record which is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSTL foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html):

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<% request.setAttribute("eInvoices", eInvoices); %>

<table>
 <c:forEach items="${eInvoices}" var="value">
  <tr><td><c:out value="${value.name}"/></td></tr>
 </c:forEach>
</table>
```

---

Use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) to get the details.

(when you click on the invoice name, an HTTP request is made to the page to get the details. These details are returned as HTML with a content-type of `'text/html'`)

Examples:

- [loading detail record through ajax](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2947/loading-detail-record-through-ajax/p1)
- [Shopify API call using AJAX and JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413020/shopify-api-call-using-ajax-and-jsp)
- [AJAX with JQuery](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/jqueryexample.html)

Comment: Hi Alexey,I have achieved this functionality. What i want to so is, when the invoices are printed, I want to click on invoice name, and clicking on that link with show me the invoice details. Right now out of my java class I am just printing invoice#, client name and date.

Comment: I just realized that I cannot use Javascript in this assignemnt. Is there any other suggestion that you can suggest ?